# Modifying Linker Script to make the .text section writable, errors

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, x86-64

I am trying to make the .text section writable for a `C` program. I looked through the options provided in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794555/how-can-i-make-gcc-compile-the-text-section-as-writable-in-an-elf-binary) and zeroed on modifying the linker script to achieve this.

- For this I created a writable memory region using

`MEMORY { rwx (wx) : ORIGIN = 0x400000, LENGTH = 256K}`

and at the section .text added:

```
.text           :
  {
 *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely)
 *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
 *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
 *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
 *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
 /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
 *(.gnu.warning)
} >rwx
```

On compiling the code with `gcc` flag `-T` and giving my linker file as an argument I am getting an error:

```
error: no memory region specified for loadable section '.interp'
```

I am only trying to change the memory permissions for the .text region. Working on Ubuntu x86_64 architecture.

Is there a better way to do this?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

The [Linker Script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzx7ivojqozk2kp/mylink.ld)

[Linker Script on pastie.org](http://pastie.org/8609434)

Comment: This is generally not a good idea. *Why* would you want it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have to modify the .text section at runtime to change some call addresses. I also tried objcopy --writable-text on an existing elf executable but that is not changing the .text section permissions(it is still AX)

Comment: If you really want to do it, I suggest you copy the default linker script, and change what you need in it. But beware that even if you make the text segment writable in the resulting executable, the operating system may still load it into read-only pages.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes I did copy the default linker script on my machine and edited it. Any idea/suggestions to rectify this error or any other work around. Thanks

Comment: W^X (never allowing segments to be both writable and executable at the same time) is a common security measure. The common way to allow changing call addresses at runtime is to add indirection: do an indirect call through a pointer. Another way without indirection would be to use STT_IFUNC, which allows selecting a function among a set of alternatives at load time (e.g. to select and appropriate optimized version for the current machine's CPU).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, you can use `mprotect()` to enable/disable text section write protection from the runtime code; see the *Notes* section in [`man 2 mprotect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html).

Here is a real-world example. First, however, a caveat:

I consider this just a proof of concept implementation, and not something I'd ever use in a real world application. It may look enticing for use in a high-performance library of some sort, but in my experience, changing the API (or the paradigm/approach) of the library usually yields much better results -- and fewer hard-to-debug bugs.

Consider the following six files:

---

**foo1.c**:

```
int foo1(const int a, const int b) { return a*a - 2*a*b + b*b; }
```

---

**foo2.c**:

```
int foo2(const int a, const int b) { return a*a + b*b; }
```

---

**foo.h.header**:

```
#ifndef   FOO_H
#define   FOO_H

extern int foo1(const int a, const int b);

extern int foo2(const int a, const int b);
```

---

**foo.h.footer**:

```
#endif /* FOO_H */
```

---

**main.c**:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int text_copy(const void *const target,
              const void *const source,
              const size_t      length)
{
    const long  page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    void       *start = (char *)target - ((long)target % page);
    size_t      bytes = length + (size_t)((long)target % page);

    /* Verify sane page size. */
    if (page < 1L)
        return errno = ENOTSUP;

    /* Although length should not need to be a multiple of page size,
     * adjust it up if need be. */
    if (bytes % (size_t)page)
        bytes = bytes + (size_t)page - (bytes % (size_t)page);

    /* Disable write protect on target pages. */
    if (mprotect(start, bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC))
        return errno;

    /* Copy code.
     * Note: if the target code is being executed, we're in trouble;
     *       this offers no atomicity guarantees, so other threads may
     *       end up executing some combination of old/new code.
    */
    memcpy((void *)target, (const void *)source, length);

    /* Re-enable write protect on target pages. */
    if (mprotect(start, bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC))
        return errno;

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("foo1(): %d bytes at %p\n", foo1_SIZE, foo1_ADDR);
    printf("foo2(): %d bytes at %p\n", foo2_SIZE, foo2_ADDR);

    printf("foo1(3, 5): %d\n", foo1(3, 5));
    printf("foo2(3, 5): %d\n", foo2(3, 5));

    if (foo2_SIZE < foo1_SIZE) {
        printf("Replacing foo1() with foo2(): ");
        if (text_copy(foo1_ADDR, foo2_ADDR, foo2_SIZE)) {
            printf("%s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Done.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Replacing foo2() with foo1(): ");
        if (text_copy(foo2_ADDR, foo1_ADDR, foo1_SIZE)) {
            printf("%s.\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Done.\n");
    }

    printf("foo1(3, 5): %d\n", foo1(3, 5));
    printf("foo2(3, 5): %d\n", foo2(3, 5));

    return 0;
}
```

---

**function-info.bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash

addr_prefix=""
addr_suffix="_ADDR"

size_prefix=""
size_suffix="_SIZE"

export LANG=C
export LC_ALL=C

nm -S "$@" | while read addr size kind name dummy ; do
    [ -n "$addr" ] || continue
    [ -n "$size" ] || continue
    [ -z "$dummy" ] || continue
    [ "$kind" = "T" ] || continue
    [ "$name" != "${name#[A-Za-z]}" ] || continue
    printf '#define %s ((void *)0x%sL)\n' "$addr_prefix$name$addr_suffix" "$addr"
    printf '#define %s %d\n' "$size_prefix$name$size_suffix" "0x$size"
done || exit $?
```

Remember to make it executable using `chmod u+x ./function-info.bash`

---

First, compile the sources using valid sizes but invalid addresses:

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 -c foo1.c
gcc -W -Wall -O3 -c foo2.c
( cat foo.h.header ; ./function-info.bash foo1.o foo2.o ; cat foo.h.footer) > foo.h
gcc -W -Wall -O3 -c main.c
```

The sizes are correct but the addresses are not, because the code is yet to be linked. Relative to the final binary, the object file contents are usually relocated at link time. So, link the sources to get example executable, **example**:

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 main.o foo1.o foo2.o -o example
```

Extract the correct (sizes and) addresses:

```
( cat foo.h.header ; ./function-info.bash example ; cat foo.h.footer) > foo.h
```

Recompile and link,

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 -c main.c
gcc -W -Wall -O3 foo1.o foo2.o main.o -o example
```

and verify that the constants now do match:

```
mv -f foo.h foo.h.used
( cat foo.h.header ; ./function-info.bash example ; cat foo.h.footer) > foo.h
cmp -s foo.h foo.h.used && echo "Done." || echo "Recompile and relink."
```

Due to high optimization (`-O3`) the code that utilizes the constants may change size, requiring a yet another recompile-relink. If the last line outputs *"Recompile and relink"*, just repeat the last two steps, i.e. five lines.

(Note that since foo1.c and foo2.c do not use the constants in foo.h, they obviously do not need to be recompiled.)

On x86_64 (GCC-4.6.3-1ubuntu5), running `./example` outputs

```
foo1(): 21 bytes at 0x400820
foo2(): 10 bytes at 0x400840
foo1(3, 5): 4
foo2(3, 5): 34
Replacing foo1() with foo2(): Done.
foo1(3, 5): 34
foo2(3, 5): 34
```

which shows that the `foo1()` function indeed was replaced. Note that the longer function is always replaced with the shorter one, because we must not overwrite any code outside the two functions.

You can modify the two functions to verify this; just remember to repeat the entire procedure (so that you use the correct _SIZE and _ADDR constants in `main()`).

Just for giggles, here is the generated `foo.h` for the above:

```
#ifndef   FOO_H
#define   FOO_H

extern int foo1(const int a, const int b);

extern int foo2(const int a, const int b);
#define foo1_ADDR ((void *)0x0000000000400820L)
#define foo1_SIZE 21
#define foo2_ADDR ((void *)0x0000000000400840L)
#define foo2_SIZE 10
#define main_ADDR ((void *)0x0000000000400610L)
#define main_SIZE 291
#define text_copy_ADDR ((void *)0x0000000000400850L)
#define text_copy_SIZE 226
#endif /* FOO_H */
```

You might wish to use a smarter scriptlet, say an `awk` one that uses `nm -S` to obtain all function names, addresses, and sizes, and in the header file replaces only the values of existing definitions, to generate your header file. I'd use a Makefile and some helper scripts.

Further notes:

- The function code is copied as-is, no relocation etc. is done. (This means that if the machine code of the replacement function contains absolute jumps, the execution continues in the original code. These example functions were chosen, because they're unlikely to have absolute jumps in them. Run `objdump -d foo1.o foo2.o` to verify from the assembly.)

  That is irrelevant if you use the example just to investigate how to modify executable code within the running process. However, if you build runtime-function-replacing schemes on top of this example, you may need to use position independent code for the replaced code (see [the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for relevant options for your architecture) or do your own relocation.
- If another thread or signal handler executes the code being modified, you're in serious trouble. You get undefined results. Unfortunately, some libraries start extra threads, which may not block all possible signals, so be extra careful when modifying code that might be run by a signal handler.
- Do not assume the compiler compiles the code in a specific way or uses a specific organization. My example uses separate compilation units, to avoid the cases where the compiler might share code between similar functions.

  Also, it examines the final executable binary directly, to obtain the sizes and addresses to be modified to modify an entire function implementation. All verifications should be done on the object files or final executable, and disassembly, instead of just looking at the C code.
- Putting any code that relies on the address and size constants into a separate compilation unit makes it easier and faster to recompile and relink the binary. (You only need to recompile the code that uses the constants directly, and you can even use less optimization for that code, to eliminate extra recompile-relink cycles, without impacting the overall code quality.)
- In my `main.c`, both the address and length supplied to `mprotect()` are page-aligned (based on the user parameters). The documents say only the address has to be. Since protections are page-granular, making sure the length is a multiple of the page size does not hurt.
- You can read and parse `/proc/self/maps` (which is a kernel-generated pseudofile; see [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), `/proc/[pid]/maps` section, for further info) to obtain the existing mappings and their protections for the current process.

In any case, if you have any questions, I'd be happy to try and clarify the above.

---

Addendum:

It turns out that using the GNU extension [`dl_iterate_phdr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) you can enable/disable write protection on all text sections trivially:

```
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <link.h>

static int do_write_protect_text(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    const int protect = (data) ? PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC : PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC;
    size_t    page;
    size_t    i;

    page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

    if (size < sizeof (struct dl_phdr_info))
        return ENOTSUP;

    /* Ignore libraries. */
    if (info->dlpi_name && info->dlpi_name[0] != '\0')
        return 0;

    /* Loop over each header. */
    for (i = 0; i < (size_t)info->dlpi_phnum; i++)
        if ((info->dlpi_phdr[i].p_flags & PF_X)) {
            size_t ptr = (size_t)info->dlpi_phdr[i].p_vaddr;
            size_t len = (size_t)info->dlpi_phdr[i].p_memsz;

            /* Start at the beginning of the relevant page, */
            if (ptr % page) {
                len += ptr % page;
                ptr -= ptr % page;
            }

            /* and use full pages. */
            if (len % page)
                len += page - (len % page);

            /* Change protections. Ignore unmapped sections. */
            if (mprotect((void *)ptr, len, protect))
                if (errno != ENOMEM)
                    return errno;
        }

    return 0;
}

int write_protect_text(int protect)
{
    int result;

    result = dl_iterate_phdr(do_write_protect_text, (void *)(long)protect);

    if (result)
        errno = result;
    return result;
}
```

Here is an example program you can use to test the above `write_protect_text()` function:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

int dump_smaps(void)
{
    FILE   *in;
    char   *line = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;

    in = fopen("/proc/self/smaps", "r");
    if (!in)
        return errno;

    while (getline(&line, &size, in) > (ssize_t)0)
        if ((line[0] >= '0' && line[0] <= '9') ||
            (line[0] >= 'a' && line[0] <= 'f'))
            fputs(line, stdout);

    free(line);

    if (!feof(in) || ferror(in)) {
        fclose(in);
        return errno = EIO;
    }

    if (fclose(in))
        return errno = EIO;

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Initial mappings:\n");
    dump_smaps();

    if (write_protect_text(0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot disable write protection on text sections: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("\nMappings with write protect disabled:\n");
    dump_smaps();

    if (write_protect_text(1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot enable write protection on text sections: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("\nMappings with write protect enabled:\n");
    dump_smaps();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The example program dumps `/proc/self/smaps` before and after changing the text section write protection, showing that it indeed does enable/disable write protectio on all text sections (program code). It does not try to alter write protect on dynamically-loaded libraries. This was tested to work on x86-64 using Ubuntu 3.8.0-35-generic kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I had tried with the mprotect() and it is working for me. I am looking to achieve the same outcome using the linker script itself so that I don't need to do the same for each program I need to make the text section writable. Thanks agian

Comment: @abhi: I'm not certain a linker script suffices. `fs/binfmt_elf.c` indicates it should, but it would not surprise me if some kernels write protect `.text` sections before `main()` is executed. Let me see if using `dl_iterate_phdr()` the above can be simplified..

Comment: @abhi: Indeed, with `dl_iterate_phdr()` you only need two trivial functions, and you can make all text sections writable (belonging to the application, not to shared libraries) using a simple function call. You can trivially make this into a `LD_PRELOAD` library, that automatically makes all text sections writable.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try your suggestion. Thanks again for such a detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to have one executable with a writable .text, you can just link with -N

At least for me, binutils 2.22 ,  ld -N objectfile.o

will produce a binary that i can happily write around in.

Reading gcc pages, you can pass the linker option from gcc by : gcc -XN source

Comment: That should probably be `-Xlinker -N` ?