# Allocate writable memory in the .text section

Tags: linux, assembly, memory-management, nasm

Is it possible to allocate memory in other sections of a NASM program, besides `.data` and `.bss`?

Say I want to write to a location in `.text` section and receive **Segmentation Fault**

I'm interested in ways to avoid this and access memory legally.  I'm running Ubuntu Linux

Comment: The `.text` section is write-protected by default on most operating systems.  Simply place whatever you want to write to into another section to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allocate memory *at runtime*, reserve some space on the stack with `sub rsp, 4096` or something.  Or run an `mmap` system call or `call malloc` from libc, if you linked against libc.

---

**If you want to test shellcode / self-modifying code**,
or have some other reason for have a writeable `.text`:

Link with `ld --omagic` or `gcc -Wl,--omagic`.  From the [`ld(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

> `-N`
> `--omagic`
> **Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable**.  Also, do not page-align the data segment, and disable linking against shared
> libraries.  If the output format supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the output as "OMAGIC".

See also [How can I make GCC compile the .text section as writable in an ELF binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794555/how-can-i-make-gcc-compile-the-text-section-as-writable-in-an-elf-binary)

---

Or probably you can use a linker script.  It might also be possible to use NASM section attribute stuff to declare a custom section that has read, write, exec permission.

**There's normally (outside of shellcode testing) no reason to do any of this, just put your static storage in `.data` or `.bss`, and your static read-only data in `.rodata` like a normal person.**

Putting read/write data near code is actively bad for performance: possible pipeline nukes from the hardware that detects self-modifying-code, and it at least pollutes the iTLB with data and the dTLB with code, if you have a page that includes some of both instead of being full of one or the other.