# Write byte to memory in .text section for testing shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, shellcode

I am writing shellcode for a buffer overflow. I want to set last byte to null in the string. The failing row is: `movb    $0, 0x07(%rdi)`. RDI has a memory address to a byte sequence "scriptN". Can someone please explain why this does not work? Here is my code

```
.section .data
# Nothing must be here

.section .text
.global main
main:

jmp     ender

starter:

xorq    %rax, %rax

popq    %rdi

# This will generate segmentation fault
movb    $0, 0x07(%rdi)

pushq   %rax
pushq   %rdi

movq    %rsp, %rsi

movb    $59, %al
syscall

xorq    %rax, %rax

movb    $60, %al
syscall


ender:
call    starter
.string "scriptN"
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in *assembly?*  "That's what compilers are for ..."

Comment: The string is in the `.text` section which by default is mapped read-only.  If you want to change that for testing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794555/how-can-i-make-gcc-compile-the-text-section-as-writable-in-an-elf-binary

Comment: By the way, if you're trying to overwrite the `N`, it's at `0x06(%rdi)` not `7`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: When I did extensive linux assembly programming I used to map everything writable. I'm not posting an answer because my technique generated everything including the ELF header file directly from the assembler output (no ld pass).

Comment: @Joshua: You can make `.text` writeable with `ld --omagic`, which would be a good way to test shellcode which is intended to run from RWX memory after a code-injection exploit.  Looking for a duplicate...